# Mysql and PHP Update Problems

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am working on a simple Userprofile, where the user can update some data over Mysql. But it doesn´t update anything. Why?

```html
<?php

if (isset($_GET['pageID'])) {

    $id = $_GET['pageID'];

    include("connector.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("    SELECT 
                            cl.clientID, cl.firstname, cl.lastname, cl.mobilephone, cl.phone, cl.client_ID,
                            ad.street, ad.city, ad.postalcode,
                            wo.work_ID,
                            ha.hardware1, ha.serialnumber, ha.hardware2, ha.serialnumber2
                            FROM client cl 
                            JOIN adress ad ON cl.clientID = ad.clientID 
                            LEFT JOIN work wo ON cl.clientID = wo.clientID
                            LEFT JOIN hardware ha ON ad.adressID = ha.adressID
                            WHERE cl.clientID = '$id'");
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>

    <div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <img src="Userfotos/jedi.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">edit Foto</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <p><h4>Lastname:</h4><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Firstname:</h4> <?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Street</h4> <?php echo $row['street']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>City</h4> <?php echo $row['city']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Postalcode</h4> <?php echo $row['postalcode']; ?></p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPrivateData">Edit data
            </button>

            <div id="editPrivateData" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Personal data</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="userProfile.php?pageID=1" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_firstname">Firstname</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_firstname" name="firstname"
                                           value="<?php echo $row['firstname']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_lastname">Lastname</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_lastname" name="lastname"
                                           value="<?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_street">Street</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_street" name="street"
                                           value="<?php echo $row['street']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_city">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_city" name="city"
                                           value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_postalcode">Postalcode</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_postalcode" name="postalcode"
                                           value="<?php echo $row['postalcode']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submitPrivate" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                                <?php

                                if (isset($_POST['submitHardware'])) {
                                    try {
                                        $id = $_GET['pageID'];
                                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE clients.client SET
                                              firstname = :firstname,
                                              lastname = :lastname,
                                              mobilephone = :mobilephone,
                                              phone = :phone
                                              WHERE clientID = $id");

                                        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
                                        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                                        $stmt->bindParam(':mobilephone', $mobilephone);
                                        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);

                                        $stmt->execute([':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
                                            ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
                                            ':mobilephone' => $_POST['mobilephone'],
                                            ':phone' => $_POST['phone']
                                        ]);
                                    } catch (PDOException $e) {
                                        echo $e->getMessage() . ", ";
                                        die("try to fix your inputs . If this doesn`t work, please contact your Admin.");
                                    }

                                }
                                ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <p><h4>Hardware1:</h4><?php echo $row['hardware1']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Serialnumber1:</h4><?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Hardware2:</h4><?php echo $row['hardware2']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Serialnumber2:</h4><?php echo $row['serialnumber2']; ?></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editHardware">Edit data
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="editHardware" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit hardware data</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="userProfile.php?pageID=3" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_hardware1">Hardware1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_hardware" name="hardware1"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['hardware1']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="serialnumber">Serialnumber1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_serialnumber" name="serialnumber"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_hardware2">Hardware2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_hardware2" name="hardware2"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['hardware2']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_serialnumber2">Serialnumber2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_serialnumber2" name="serialnumber2"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['serialnumber2']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submitHardware" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                                <?php

                                                                if (isset($_POST['submitHardware'])) {
                                                                    require("connector.php");
                                                                    try {
                                                                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE clients.hardware SET
                                                                                                              hardware1 = :hardware1,
                                                                                                              serialnumber = :serialnumber,
                                                                                                              hardware2 = :hardware2,
                                                                                                              serialnumber2 = :serialnumber2,
                                                                                                              WHERE hardware.clientID = '$id'");

                                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
                                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
                                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':mobilephone', $mobilephone);
                                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
                                                                        $stmt->bindParam(':client_ID', $client_ID);

                                                                        $stmt->execute([':hardware1' => $_POST['hardware1'],
                                                                            ':serialnumber' => $_POST['serialnumber'],
                                                                            ':hardware2' => $_POST['hardware2'],
                                                                            ':serialnumber2' => $_POST['seerialnumber2']
                                                                        ]);

                                                                    } catch (PDOException $e) {

                                                                        echo $e->getMessage() . ", ";
                                                                        die("try to fix your inputs . If this doesn`t work, please contact your Admin.");
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                 ?>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <p><h4>ClientID:</h4><?php echo $row['client_ID']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>WorkID:</h4><?php echo $row['work_ID']; ?></p>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Edit data</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

As you can see, there is a `while-loop` to fetch the data and display them into some fields. In Between this loop, i created two `Bootstrap-Modals`, where the user can edit something. if the user clicks on the "save" button, nothing happens. i really don`t understand where is the problem.

and another small point: the userprofile is generated dynamically with the clientID(pageID). how do i temporary save this pageID, so i can return to the current page after the form action `method ="POST"`

The clientID is the primary key in the database for the clients.client table. The client_ID is an ID the user has to set by himself, he can set whatever he want to. The PageID is linked to the clientID is for generating dynamical pages. That means: on another page there is a table which displays some basically informations about all users. If the logged in User clicks on a user from the table, there will be the userprofile dynamically generated.

Comment: Remove pageID=1 from url

Comment: don't put your update logic into the loop man

Comment: if you click save does your page refresh?

Comment: Don't be sorry, just fix the mistakes, especially lack of capital letters.

Comment: @Christoph you can store pageID in hidden filed and it will get posted when form submits

Comment: and manalin: i will try what you said, thanks.

Comment: yes, the page refreshes on a click on save

Comment: hey, thanks @shasi for your answer:but how do i reconnect to the specific UserID page? if i just write <form action="userProfile.php" method="post"> it will return to the mainUserprofile, not to the speciffic userprofile –

Comment: @Shashi, how to do that?

Comment: @madalin ivascu now i took the complete Modal outside the loop, but nothing changed...it does not update.

Comment: I think something in this php update statement is wrong, but i really don´t know what

Answer (score 0):

your code is really weird. Please tell us what the page ID and client ID are. They are obviously not the same. But you use them as such. I reduced your code to just one modal and used hidden fields for client and page ID values.

```
<?php


// TODO: filter all input
if (isset($_POST['submitHardware']) && $_POST['pageID'] == 3) {
    try {
        include("connector.php");

        $client_id = $_GET['clientID'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE clients.client SET
              firstname = :firstname,
              lastname = :lastname,
              mobilephone = :mobilephone,
              phone = :phone
              WHERE clientID = $client_id");

        $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
        $stmt->bindParam(':mobilephone', $mobilephone);
        $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);

        $stmt->execute([':firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
            ':lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
            ':mobilephone' => $_POST['mobilephone'],
            ':phone' => $_POST['phone']
        ]);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . ", ";
        die("try to fix your inputs . If this doesn`t work, please contact your Admin.");
    }

}

if (isset($_GET['clientID'])) {

    $client_id = $_GET['clientID']; // TODO: filter

    include("connector.php");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("    SELECT 
                            cl.clientID, cl.firstname, cl.lastname, cl.mobilephone, cl.phone, cl.client_ID,
                            ad.street, ad.city, ad.postalcode,
                            wo.work_ID,
                            ha.hardware1, ha.serialnumber, ha.hardware2, ha.serialnumber2
                            FROM client cl 
                            JOIN adress ad ON cl.clientID = ad.clientID 
                            LEFT JOIN work wo ON cl.clientID = wo.clientID
                            LEFT JOIN hardware ha ON ad.adressID = ha.adressID
                            WHERE cl.clientID = '$client_id'");
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>

    <div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <img src="Userfotos/jedi.jpg" class="img-responsive"><br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">edit Foto</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3 profileNames">
            <p><h4>Hardware1:</h4><?php echo $row['hardware1']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Serialnumber1:</h4><?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Hardware2:</h4><?php echo $row['hardware2']; ?></p>
            <p><h4>Serialnumber2:</h4><?php echo $row['serialnumber2']; ?></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editHardware">Edit data
            </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="editHardware" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit hardware data</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="userProfile.php" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="pageID" value="3">
                                <input type="hidden" name="clientID" value="<?php echo $client_id; ?>">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_hardware1">Hardware1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_hardware" name="hardware1"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['hardware1']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="serialnumber">Serialnumber1</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_serialnumber" name="serialnumber"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['serialnumber']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_hardware2">Hardware2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_hardware2" name="hardware2"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['hardware2']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="_serialnumber2">Serialnumber2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="_serialnumber2" name="serialnumber2"
                                           placeholder="<?php echo $row['serialnumber2']; ?>">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submitHardware" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```